# scan a file and write in it if regex is matched

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know if it was possible to, when opening a file, scan it entirely and if a defined regex is set up write some lines in the file.

I did not find anything that could do it.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: what to do the next time you open the file, write the lines again

Comment: delete the lines when I close the file would be great ! :D

Comment: Easy to do in an extension.  It could be done with a keybinding too - how do you normally open files?

Comment: wdym ? I have my workspace and I open them from it

Comment: There are a lot of ways to open files.  Some will have associated commands that could be useful in an answer.